# Difference between Of android

Tags: android

totally puzzled in these similar type of attributes

for id's

```
id= "android:id/Some"
```

and

```
id= "@+id/Some"
```

and for width

```
layout_width=
```

and

```
width
```

for gravity

```
layout_gravity
```

and

```
gravity
```

and any more else you would like to tell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`id= "android:id/Some"` is an id defined in the system defaults.  `id="@+id/Some"` is a local id you create in your application (the "+" means it is an on-the-fly definition, i.e it is not defined in the id.xml file).

`layout_width=""` is the width your view will have in its parent. It can be `wrap_content`, `match_parent` or a dimension. `width` can be used to achieve the same result as the `layout_width`.

`layout_gravity` used to tell how this view will be placed in its parent (i.e `layout_gravity="bottom"` on a TextView will place the view at the bottom). `gravity` is how the child-views of this view will be placed within this (i.e `gravity="bottom"` on a TextView places the text at the bottom).

Generally the `layout_` attributes relates to how the current View should behave inside its parent. attributes without `layout_` determines how the content of the view behaves.

Answer (score 1):

for id, @ tells android you're talking about a resource (which will be compiled into R.java).
+ means you're creating a new resource rather than referencing an existing one.

layout_width (and layout_height) can be either "wrap_content" or "fill_parent" ("match_parent" in API >= 11).

width (and height) is the actual width of the component in the specified units (px, sp, dip etc.)

layout_gravity specifies the gravity of the children. gravity specifies the component's own gravity.

Answer (score 1):

You should read [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html), some attributes are inherited from android.view.View and others are the objects attributes.

Answer (score 1):

1. id= "android:id/Some" ---- use an id named "Some" which already exists
2. id= "@+id/Some" ---- set up a new id named "Some"
3. layout_width ---- layout parameter for all View object which is always necessary
4. width ---- just for TextView and its subclass's object, this is optional for TextView
5. gravity ---- set the position of the content in the view itself
6. layout_gravity ---- set the position of the view how to be positioned in its parent

you need read more about official documents, try the code in a LinearLayout below to see how this works

```
enter <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/some"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:width="100dip"
    android:height="100dip"
    android:text="SAMPLE"
    android:gravity="center"
    />
<TextView 
    android:id="@id/more"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="SAMPLE"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    /></LinearLayout>here
```